# Can we combine frontend and backend to make make user and deleteuser platform

Tags: reactjs, express, react-hooks, graphql, graphiql

I am combining react and graphql in a project.For that first, I have created a server of graphql

```
const graphql = require("graphql");
const {
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLSchema,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLList,
} = graphql;
const userData = require("../MOCK_DATA.json");

const UserType = require("./TypeDefs/UserType");
const RemoveUserType = require("./TypeDefs/RemoveUserType");

const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "RootQueryType",
  fields: {
    getAllUsers: {
      type: new GraphQLList(UserType),
      args: { id: { type: GraphQLInt } },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return userData;
      },
    },
  },
});

const Mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: "Mutation",
  fields: {
    createUser: {
      type: UserType,
      args: {
        firstName: { type: GraphQLString },
        lastName: { type: GraphQLString },
        email: { type: GraphQLString },
        password: { type: GraphQLString },
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        userData.push({
          id: userData.length + 1,
          firstName: args.firstName,
          lastName: args.lastName,
          email: args.email,
          password: args.password,
        });
        return args;
      },
    },
    removeUser: {
      type: RemoveUserType,
      args: {
        id:{type: GraphQLInt},
        email: { type: GraphQLString },
        password: { type: GraphQLString },
      },
      resolve(args) {
        if(userData[args.id].email === args.email &&  userData[args.id].password === args.password ){
          console.log(userData[args.id])
            delete userData[args.id]
        }else{
            console.log("You cannot do that")
        }
        return args;
      },
    }
  },
});

module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({ query: RootQuery, mutation: Mutation });
```

And I have linked the client and the server with the Apollo client and apollo provider

```
"use client"

import type { Metadata } from 'next'
import { Inter } from 'next/font/google'
import './globals.css'
import Header from './components/Header'
import {
  ApolloClient,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloProvider,
  HttpLink,
  from,
} from "@apollo/client";
import { onError } from "@apollo/client/link/error";
import GetUsers from "./components/GetUsers";
import Form from "./components/Form";

const errorLink = onError(({ graphqlErrors, networkError }:any) => {
  if (graphqlErrors) {
    graphqlErrors.map(({ message, location, path }:any) => {
      alert(`Graphql error ${message}`);
    });
  }
});
const link = from([
  errorLink,
  new HttpLink({ uri: "http://localhost:6969/graphql" }),
]);
const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  link: link,
});



const inter = Inter({ subsets: ['latin'] })



export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body className={inter.className}>
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <Header/>
        {children}
        </ApolloProvider>
      </body>
      
    </html>
  )
}
```

Next, I have made the mutations on client side like we will give on apollo client.

```
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

export const CREATE_USER_MUTATION = gql`
  mutation createUser(
    $firstName: String!
    $lastName: String!
    $email: String!
    $password: String
  ) {
    createUser(
      firstName: $firstName
      lastName: $lastName
      email: $email
      password: $password
    ) {
      id
    }
  }
`;
export const REMOVE_USER_MUTATION = gql`
mutation removeUser(
  $id:Number!
  $email: String!
  $password: String!
){
  removeUser(
    id:$id
    email: $email
    password: $password
  )
}
`;
```

Lastly I have used the mutations in a react component using useMutation hook.

```
"use client"

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { REMOVE_USER_MUTATION } from "../GraphQL/Mutations";
import { useMutation } from "@apollo/client";


const FormForDeleteUsers = () => {
  const [id, setId] = useState(Number);
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [removeUser, { error }] = useMutation(REMOVE_USER_MUTATION);

  const deleteUser = () => {
    console.log(id)
    console.log(email)
    console.log(password)
    console.log(removeUser)

    removeUser({
      variables: {
        id:id,
        email: email,
        password: password,
      },
    });
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <input className="py-5 px-12 rounded-sm outline-lime-400  mb-3 border-black border"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Email"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setEmail(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
       <input className="py-5 px-12 rounded-sm outline-lime-400  border-black border"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Password"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setPassword(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
       <input className="py-5 px-12 rounded-sm outline-lime-400  border-black border"
        type="text"
        placeholder="Id"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setId(e.target.value);
        }}
      />
       <button onClick={deleteUser} className="mt-5 py-5 px-16 bg-green-500 rounded-md hover:bg-lime-500"> Remove User</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default FormForDeleteUsers
```

Also I forgot To add one I used express graphql to make a graphql server for backend

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const PORT = 6969;
const { graphqlHTTP } = require("express-graphql");
const schema = require("./Schemas/index");
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.json());
app.use(
  "/graphql",
  graphqlHTTP({
    schema,
    graphiql: true,
  })
);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log("Server running");
});
```

I will run node index.js for server and npm run dev for client and create user mutation works fine but remove user does not work  it shows server error server responded with responed status 400. I have checked everything I could in the server part.Is there anything wrong in client or server part for removeUser.

Comment: A 400 typically points to invalid query/mutation syntax and/or types. If you use GraphiQL to look at the `removeUser` mutation what does it tell you its return type is? If it expects to return something other than `void` then you'll need to specify some fields to select from the mutation.

Comment: I have looked at the GraphiQL for that mutation. First it is not Number for type of id in  mutations on client side .It is Int. I solved that problem it is still showing the same error in my website. I again went to GraphiQl to check out. I can't figure anything. Also I don't understand what u are telling . I only get error as result when I enter the mutation. What is selecting some fields from a mutation? How to do that? If I can get answers for these I think I can figure out the solution .Hope you would clarify me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please try to run the mutation in GraphiQL first.

Comment: How can run the mutation in Graphiql? I dont know the exact and correct way of running the mutation

Comment: yeah,now I found out how to make a mutation it is showing cannot read properties of undefined(reading id

Comment: That means your resolver (on the server) has errors. Different problem.

Comment: I cant find anything in my resolver . I've searched a lot. Can you find anything?

Answer (score 0):

Your function signature in your resolver is missing the `parent` argument which is first, followed by args. Change:

```
resolve(args) {
  if(userData[args.id].email === args.email && 
    userData[args.id].password === args.password ){
```

to

```
resolve(parent,args) {
  if(userData[args.id].email === args.email &&
    userData[args.id].password === args.password ){
```

On the client, change your mutation code to:

```
export const REMOVE_USER_MUTATION = gql`
mutation removeUser( $id: Int!, $email: String!, $password: String! ) {
  removeUser(id: $id, email: $email, password: $password) {
    id
  }
}`;
```

(Please note the commas between the arguments to the GraphQL operations)

Comment: Thank you so much .Now the resolver error solved .If I run a mutation in graphiql it works. But now the client isnt working properly. I don't know what to do. Like you said on first it is now the mutation (on client side) problem.Do you find any mistake in client side also?

Comment: Please include the graphiql mutation graphql code that works (including the variables and any headers) and then we can compare to your code. They are clearly not the same.

Comment: mutation{
  removeUser(id:100,email:"dcallendar2s@live.com",password:"27KCuy8is") {
    id
     email
     password
  }
}

Comment: This is the mutation syntax that works on graphiql.

Comment: removeUser: {
      type: RemoveUserType,
      args: {
        id: { type: GraphQLInt },
        email: { type: GraphQLString },
        password: { type: GraphQLString },
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        console.log(userData[999])
        if(userData[args.id].email === args.email &&  userData[args.id].password === args.password ){
          console.log(userData[args.id])
            delete userData[args.id]
        }else{
            console.log("You cannot do that")
        }
        return args;
      },
    }

Comment: This is the graphql code that works . I think the problem lies in the mutation syntax on the client side which I have added earlier . I don't know correctly But I think that's the problem

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: See the update to the answer.

Comment: It still shows "ApolloError : Response not successful: Received status code 400". I have made the changes correctly .On the server side it is perfect.On the client also it is perfect.But I think the useMutation hook and the removeUser func is the problem.Can you check that also once please.I cannot find anything

Comment: Sir did you find anything? Plz help me out

Comment: If a mutation works in GraphiQL it will work in `useMutation` as long as it is *exactly* the same. You have a simple typo somewhere.

Comment: On the client side?

Comment: `useMutation` is client side

Comment: https://github.com/Harikrishnaselvam/JoinMe.git

Comment: Sir, I can't find anything.I have added git hub repo link .Can you please find the mistake

Comment: Sir I found the error and solved. It was two problems. First is that , in the mutation syntax you send, it is not number for type Id, it is Int. Second is that the input value coming from the Id input is a string and I parsed it and used it in the usemutation hook